# Можно ли убить Runnable task внути run()

Tags: java, многопоточность, scheduler

Передо мной стоит следующая задача - нужно оставить опрашивать сервер после того как проверяемое поле станет равно *"ready"* (образно). Каждый раз, когда я создаю определенный объект и передаю его на сервер, я каждый 2 секунды проверяю не изменилось ли состояние каждого такого объекта (*REST*) с помощью `scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableTask, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`. Если одно из полей конкретного объекта станет равно *"ready"*, то я должен убить поток который опрашивал этот объект, но остальные объекты должны продолжать опрашиваться. Я попробовал сделать проверку на *"ready"* прямо внутри `run()` и за ней `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`; но это не сработало, поток не остановился (код ниже). Как можно реализовать остановку конкретно потока?

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(50);

public void checkById(String id) {
    Runnable runnableTask = () -> {
        Pojo pojo = getById(id);
        if (pojo.getStatus.equals("ready")) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    };
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableTask, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: можно кинуть исключение. `throw new CancellationException();` вместо `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Преимущество при использовании `Executors`: с тредами работают за вас. Так что вам не нужно убивать тред (к тому же `interrupt()` несколько для другого нужен), а нужно отменить запланированное повторение таска.

Изнутри, наверное, проще всего выбросить исключение при выполнении нужного условия. Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), это предотвращает последующие выполнения этого задания.

```
Runnable task2 = () -> {
  ...
  if (...) throw new CancellationException();
};
```

Для полноты картины, снаружи это можно сделать используя объект, возвращаемый методом `scheduleAtFixedRate`:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> t =
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableTask, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if (...) {
  t.cancel(false);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Тогда у меня еще вопрос, если я остановлюсь на втором варианте (остановка снаружи) то в этот if(...) я буду заходить при каждом повторении таски (нужно именно так)?  Просто сам метод checkById() вызывается единожды для каждого объекта, но сама таска повторяется пока статус не станет "ready"

Comment: Снаружи, значит, в том потоке, из которого вы задания создаёте с помощью `scheduleAtFixedRate`. От вас зависит, дальнейший ход выполнения программы. Вы можете сделать, например, чтобы метод `checkById` возвращал `ScheduledFuture` и складывать их вместе с `String id` в `Map<String, ScheduledFuture<?>>`, и при выполнении условия внутри таска вытаскивать ссылку и вызывать `cancel`. Хотя получается, всё равно изнутри) Потому что условие проверять внутри таска удобнее. Кажется, в вашем случае проще исключения кидать)

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое